# Google Analytics Not showing data past 6 months

Tags: google-analytics

I have a GA environment that has many years worth of data, but when I go into a filter at the Landing Page level and filter down into an advanced (e.g.: Show containing "page name") it only shows me data starting in July. Nothing past that. I remove the filter to see all pages, then I get my full data view.

Any ideas what could be happening there?

Brian

Comment: Are you sure that page name exists before July? Are you using segments or only filters?

Comment: We are using filters. What I can trace back is the team set up sub domain tracking at the same time. Would that do it?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the comment to the main post, it is normal Analytics behavior. If you have set up a subdomain tracking in July in the same Property, using a filter for a subdomain page, you only see the data from July onwards, since that page did not exist before.

Comment: Thanks.

So here is what I have:

View 1: Primary Domain (4 years old) 
View 2: sub domain set up in July
View 3: sub domain set up in July

When I look at the Primary domain, it does not show me any data prior to the day that the subdomain views were set up. That's what is throwing me. Why would my main view, separate from the sub domains not show me anything past July?

Comment: What filter did you use? If you have filtered something that is only on the subdomain, it is normal that it does not show anything before its existence, that is, before its data has been tracked. Can you provide some screenshot?